# Vectors disjunction

Tags: c++, vector, std

Which is the most elegant way to implement a logical disjunction between two std::vectors in c++?

as example:

```
vector a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
vector b = {0,1,2,3,4};
vector c = a-b;

print c = {5,6,7,8,9}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference), sequences should be sorted.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> c;
std::set_difference
(
   a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(c)
);
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `std::inserter` with a vector; insertion will invalidate the iterator it uses.  `std::back_inserter` should do the job, however; `std::set_difference` should generate the values in order.

Comment: Also, you really should indent `std::inserter...`, or put it on the same line as the `std::set_difference`.  As you've currently formatted the code, it's confusing.

Comment: @JamesKanze inserter is used in example on cppreference, so, I just take it from there.

Comment: So there's an error in cppreference.  On verifying the exact specification of `std::inserter`, it should work, because the standard adds enough constraints to protect against iterator invalidation.  But `std::back_inserter` is simpler, and I would argue preferable.